# go-redis: TTL returns a negative duration when the key does not exist

Tags: go, redis, ttl

I am using [go-redis](https://github.com/go-redis/redis) to interact with a REDIS server (version 3.2.100).

According to the [Redis documentation](https://redis.io/commands/ttl), if a key does not exist, then the command TTL should return the value -2.

However, if the key does not exist, the method TTL returns a value which represents some duration (-2s), instead of an integer.

The code below illustrates this behaviour.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/go-redis/redis"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Print("Create a REDIS client now.\n")
    client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     "localhost:6379",
        Password: "", // no password set
        DB:       0,  // use default DB
    })

    ttl, _ := client.TTL("MyKey").Result()
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", ttl)
    if ttl < 0 {
        if -1 == ttl.Seconds() {
            fmt.Print("The key will not expire.\n")
        } else if -2 == ttl.Seconds() {
            fmt.Print("The key does not exist.\n")
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Unexpected error %d.\n", ttl.Seconds())
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Create a REDIS client now.
-2s
The key does not exist.
```

Is it OK ? I think that the GO method TTL should return an integer, instead of a negative duration.

Comment: The behaviour is documented in the package as [such](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-redis/redis#DurationCmd.Result). If you don't think it's ok open an issue on github not a question on SO.

Comment: Go is statically typed. TTL returns a duration. It can't sometimes return an integer instead of a duration.

Comment: @mkopriva to be precise behavior for negative ttl is not documented at go-redis, unless you treat the source as ultimate documentation ;). Also, it's perfectly valid to post a question to SO when having doubts, especially that the OP provided valid piece of code. Cheers

Comment: @WojciechKaczmarek the negative value is documented in the redis documentation, the return type is documented in the go-redis documentation. His problem is that he's getting back a `time.Duration` instead of an `int`. Why the TTL method in the go-redis package returns a time.Duration instead of an int is a question to the developers of that package.

Comment: You pointed to the go-redis doc not the original Redis doc, that's why I started this conversation in the first place.

Comment: I also don't quite get the idea that this question would be invalid. It's perfectly valid and good formulated question when one has doubts about an API.

Comment: @WojciechKaczmarek you don't have to get the idea, you like the question? Fine by me. I've pointed to go-redis docs because his main problem is the type returned by the `DurationCmd.Result` method. Quoting OP: `I think that the GO method TTL should return an integer, instead of a negative duration.` you can see their problem is the type of the return value in case it's negative, so it seems they are fine with a positive duration just not  a negative one, but Go is a statically typed language and you can't have a single method return two different types based on some arbitrary criteria.

Comment: You pointed to the place with no documentation (just a function/method signature is hardly a documentation) saying the behavior is documented. That looks more like attempt to bash the question, not to help the guy.

Comment: Also, statical typedness is not exactly the point. There are languages statically typed with variant types / ADTs, where function could return different types.

Answer (score 1):

It is more useful to get TTL of the existing key from redis as time.Duration. -1 and -2 are the exceptions, asserted to the primary type. Maybe it could be more convenient if TTL returned (*DurationCmd, error) but I didn't dive deep into go-redis logic. I don't see a problem here. Just consider your always get time.Duration as a result.

Comment: DurationCmd itself returns (time.Duration, error) upon calling Result. The issue is rather that, if I understand correctly, OP would rather see special cases of negative ttl as errors. I tend to agree this would be more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

In this implementation of Redis client `TTL` is returning `*DurationCmd` which itself doesn't interpret `-2` and `-1` in any special way, so after calling `Result` the value is represented as `time.Duration`.

Then your code is correct; please also note `time.Duration` is just a wrapped int with a special `Stringer` implementation, thus you have this misleading `-2s` output.

It would be more elegant for your code to simply print the duration after checking for special negative cases. <strike>By the way, you don't need to call `duration.Seconds()`</strike> With regard to comparison - you can directly compare `time.Duration` to raw int, but then the returned value would be in nanoseconds - even more mimsleading (thanks @Peter for pointing that); so, you're doing the right thing with `ttl.Seconds()`.

Please also note it'd be better to not ignore error where you call `Result`, so the line would become:

```
ttl, err := client.TTL("MyKey").Result()
```

If you feel that it would be more valid and elegant to treat `-2` and `-1` as special cases requiring dedicated errors, then there's a space to open an issue on GitHub.

Hope this helps,

Comment: The value would be -2e9 though, not -2 (nanosecond).